# how to enter bootloader with moboot in HP Touchpad

Tags: bootloader

I have a HP Touchpad that successfully installed webos and CM9 with moboot to select which to boot. Today, I want to update CM9 to CM10.1 or CM11, and here come the problems: it couldn't install the zip I downloaded and I thought it's because the recovery is too old, which is CWM v5.x(I can't remember precisely). so I install a CWM v6.x, but it can't work either.

Now, I want to flash the CWM v5.x back, and it seems using fastboot is the only way. But with moboot, I just can't enter bootloader mode, the only selections available are WebOS, CM and CWM.

Can someone tell me how to enter bootloader, so that I can flash the older CWM back, and restore my data? For now, I can only enter WebOS, and the Android system won't work: it just turns black after the splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that moboot in touchpad is corresponding to the bootloader in android native device, so I think it may be impossible to enter such a 'bootloader' in hp touchpad.